# Bean validation in Spring Webflux.fn

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, bean-validation, spring-validation

I'm trying to implement standard bean validation in our project which is using Spring Webflux with functional endpoints.

Spring Boot Version: 2.7.14
Spring Boot Starter Validation: 2.7.14

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.14</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried the steps on below link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/beanvalidation.html

DTOObject:

```
@Data
public class DTOObject {
   @NotBlank
   private String name;
}
```

I created a bean of LocalValidatorFactoryBean.clas

```
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
```

I injected the Validator bean in my Request handler class:

```
@Inject
private Validator validator;
```

Then, I called validate method on the DTO object inside a Mono.map()/flatmap():

```
validator.validate(dtoObject);
```

However, the validation isn't happening.

Can someone please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: How have you used it in the `map` method. You shouildn't use a `version` for the dependency (assuming you have `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent in your project. Nor should you configure the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` as Spring Boot already configures it. The fact that you have done both makes me wonder what you added more.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just added the version here to show. It's actually coming from parent. I wasn't aware that Spring already configures LocalValidatorFactoryBean. I will add the config/code in question to a test codebase and try. Anything else wrong with the code/config?